# Bing webmaster tools malware history

Tags: malware, bing-webmaster-tools

I received a warning in Bing webmaster tools that one of my site pages was infected with malware. this message was delivered several days ago, and unfortunately I only was informed of it today.
Currently the malware tab is empty. The message itself is very generic and does not include a specific URL that was affected. I checked the home page and it does not look like anything was injected there.
Is there a way to know which page exactly was affected? Can I assume it was only one page and there is no threat now?

Comment: It could be a glitch. If you use Google Search Console, you can check that, and possibly do a site: directive in the search text box (Google and Bing) and see if there is a warning in the SERPs. As well, there are several online malware scanners that may help, though I have never used one.

Comment: I had the same problem.   Bing randomly reported something as malware, didn't provide any details, and then removed the warning a few days later.